# Amazon Ec2 VM import always end up on throwing "Internal Server Error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-vm-import

When I try to import a raw using [vm-import](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-vm-image) , then I get the status message of the import-progress and it show's the percent till 41% then it says 
 **StatusMessage: ServerError: an internal error has occurred during conversion.,Status: active**

I know something has happened in their end . But Is there any way to at least get some information about the error occurred in server ? or there is no other way to get any information about the error occurred in the server?